# macOS 12.2.X (Monterey) as a developer account -- how can I "csrutil disable" all my APFS partitions?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-mavericks

I'm running macOS 12.2.1, the latest Apple OS Monterey, with Xcode, and signed in with my apple developer account.

How can I use "csrutil disable" or "spctl --master-disable" on each of my APFS partitions? I am always hit with a permission or access denied to System-wide folders and mounts. If this is not possible, can I revert back to macOS (HFS) and do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do this in recoveryOS, then open up Terminal. Whether it sticks or not, I don't know. It will make you reboot after running the commands.

Comment: After I reboot, it resets back to being enable'd and I cannot write to these partitions. I guess I could just copy everything to a remote drive, create a HFS+ drive, and not use APFS?